Show that $S(\omega) := \sum _{i=1}^{Y(\omega)} X_i(\omega)$ is a square-integrable random variable in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$

Let $n \in \Bbb N,M \geq 0$ be constants,$( \Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ be a probability space, $Y : \Omega \to  \{0,1,\dots ,n\}$ a random variable and $X_1,\dots, X_n : 
[-M,M]$ random variables with:
(i) $Y,X_1,\dots, X_n$ are stochastically independent,
(ii) $E(X_1) = E(X_i) \text{for}  i = 1,\dots,n$.
Show that
$$S(\omega) := \sum _{i=1}^{Y(\omega)} X_i(\omega)$$
is a square-integrable random variable in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$

Attempt:
To show that $( S(\omega) : = \sum_{i=1}^{Y(\omega)} X_i(\omega) )$ is a square-integrable random variable in $( L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) )$, we need to check that the expected value of the square of $( S(\omega) )$ is finite, i.e. $( \mathbb{E}[S^2] < \infty )$.
Expected value of $ S(\omega) $:
$
   \mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{Y} X_i\right].
   $
Since $ Y $ and the $ X_i $ are stochastically independent, we can exchange the sum for the expected value:
$
   \mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{Y} X_i\right] = \mathbb{E}[Y] \cdot \mathbb{E}[X_1]
   $
To show that $ S $ is square-integrable, we consider $ \mathbb{E}[S^2] :$
$$
   S^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{Y} X_i\right)^2
    = \sum_{i=1}^{Y} X_i^2 + 2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq Y} X_i X_j$$
Expected value of
$S^2$:
Due to stochastic independence, the following applies:
$$
   \Bbb E [S^2] = \Bbb E \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{Y} X_i\right)^2\right]
    = \Bbb E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{Y} X_i^2\right] + 2 \Bbb E \left[  \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq Y} X_i X_j \right]$$
Now we use the fact that $X_i $ are stochastically independent and identically distributed:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[S^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y] \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] + 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\binom{Y}{2}\right] \mathbb{E}[X_1]^2$$
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\binom{Y}{2}\right] = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[Y(Y-1)] $$.
To ensure that $ \mathbb{E}[S^2] $ is finite, $ \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] $ and $ \mathbb{E}[Y^2] $ must be finite:
$$
   \mathbb{E}[S^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y] \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] + \mathbb{E}[Y(Y-1)] \mathbb{E}[X_1]^2.
   $$
Since $ \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] < \infty  (\text{because}  X_1 $ is square-integrable) and $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] < \infty $ (because $ Y$  is a random variable and is assumed to be in a finite range), it follows that $ \mathbb{E}[S^2] < \infty $.
We have thus shown that $ S(\omega) $ is a square-integrable random variable in $ L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) $.

If I understand your notation correctly, $|S(\omega)| \le n M$ for every $\omega$. In that case, $S(\omega)^2 \le n^2 M^2$, so $\mathbb{E}[S(\omega)^2] \le n^2 M^2 < \infty$. Perhaps the point of the exercise is not to show the square integrability, but the measurability.

I would also point out that $\mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ doesn't follow immediately from the fact that $X_i$ and $Y$ are independent: that needs to be proven.  However, as @JasonSwanson points out, showing $S$ is bounded isn't too difficult.
